# Always report network not available when using NetworkInfo program

Tags: android

I have wrote a program to check if the network is available or not. Here is my simple code:

```
     public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
      ConnectivityManager connectivity=ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivity == null) {
  boitealerte(this.getString(R.string.alert),"getSystemService rend null");
   } else {
  NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
  if (info != null) {
     for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
           return true;
          }
       }
    }
 }
   return false;
   }
```

I run it on my Android phone, it always returns false but the network is available and I can make calls.

Answer (score 1):

The state NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED tells you if you have a data connection (either via wifi or mobile. Not a "talk" phone connection.

Comment: I would like to know if the "mobile network" is available or not (i.e. our of service or coverage area). Is that possible with this program

Comment: I also tried this code 'code'final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = 
connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if( mobile.isAvailable() ){
    //Do something else.
                } It does not work, the mobile.isAvailable() always returns false.

Comment: The ConnectivityManager ONLY deals with data connections. For phone signal details check out this tutorial: http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/

Comment: That was helpful but sometimes the network becomes not available even the signal strength is strong like 70%. What I want to detect is when the service (mobile network) is not available, the case where only emergency call is available and there is a ! yellow sign in the up-left corner of the phone.